# Open gmail compose in new window using javascript with option to close

Tags: javascript, gmail, google-apps

I know that I can open gmail compose in new window using `http://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1`, but I want it to be exactly same as gmail compose when we click compose button to open it. I am not seeing any option to get that look, for example atleast the close button. I need help regarding this.

Comment: Can't I do that then?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of opening the compose in its own window is to actually hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you click the <kbd>**`Compose`**</kbd> button.

If you use Keyboard Shortcuts, you can also open a New Compose Window in a popup window by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

No need for extra scripts or plugins to accomplish what you want, and for security and performance, you should always seek to solve browser and website problems with as little interference from 3rd-party plugins and scripts.

Alternatively, when you hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click the <kbd>**`Compose`**</kbd> button, your Compose window will open in a background tab (in browsers that support tabs, like Google Chrome).